# Get matching interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, intervals

So I start with **two simple things**:

- A list of **time Intervals** with it's matching interval name.
- And a **currentTime** like e.g (`"08:58"`, `"15:23"`, `"02:03"`).

---

```
let intervals = {
    "08:00 - 09:00" : "Morning yoga",
    "09:00 - 10:00" : "Breakfast",
    "10:00 - 13:00" : "School Period",
    "13:00 - 14:00" : "Basketball",
    "14:00 - 16:00" : "Free Period",
    "16:00 - 17:00" : "Evening Meal",
    "17:00 - 18:00" : "Exercise Period",
    "18:00 - 19:00" : "Shower Block",
    "19:00 - 22:00" : "Evening Free Time",
    "22:00 - 23:00" : "Evening Rollcall",
    "23:00 - 08:00" : "Lights Out"
  }
```

I'd like to extract the **interval's name** to the given **currentTime** so that I get for example from:

- `"08:58"` the result: `"Morning yoga"`
- `"15:23"` the result: `"Free Period"`
- `"02:03"` the result: `"Lights Out"`

---

What I got so far is the code below but obviously there are some error inside.

```js
let getSchedule = function(time) {
  let scheduleIndex = 0;
  let current = getMinute(time);
  let intervalArray = []

  for (let key in schedule)
    intervalArray.push([getMinute(key.split(" - ")[0]),
      getMinute(key.split(" - ")[1])
    ]);

  for (let index = 0; index < intervalArray.length; index++) {
    let interval = intervalArray[index]
    if (current >= interval[0] && current < interval[1]) {
      scheduleIndex = index;
      break;
    }
  };
  return schedule[Object.keys(schedule)[scheduleIndex]]
}

let getMinute = function(time) {
  let hour = parseInt(time.split(":")[0]),
    minute = parseInt(time.split(":")[1]);
  return minute + hour * 60;
}

let result = getSchedule("16:22")
console.log(result)

result = getSchedule("02:00")
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script>
  let schedule = {
    "08:00 - 09:00": "Morning yoga",
    "09:00 - 10:00": "Breakfast",
    "10:00 - 13:00": "School Period",
    "13:00 - 14:00": "Basketball",
    "14:00 - 16:00": "Free Period",
    "16:00 - 17:00": "Evening Meal",
    "17:00 - 18:00": "Exercise Period",
    "18:00 - 19:00": "Shower Block",
    "19:00 - 22:00": "Evening Free Time",
    "22:00 - 23:00": "Evening Rollcall",
    "23:00 - 08:00": "Lights Out"
  }
</script>
```

**Edit**: Note that the full hours will change the state so that *23:00* has the state `Lights Out` while *22:59* has the state `Evening Rollcall`.

Please note also that I can not change the `intervals` object. It's structure must be kept.

Comment: You say obviously there is some error - please add detail of what the error is, thanks.

Comment: so what do you expect if the time is e.g. 23:00 ?

Comment: @CrayonViolent: The full hours will change the state so that **23:00** has the state `Lights Out` while **22:59** has the state `Evening Rollcall`.

Comment: Is your `intervals` format/structure required to be that way? Because there are a number of other ways you could structure it to make coding for what you want to do a lot more easy/elegant..

Comment: The actual problem statement is not contained in the question.  On the face of it, the question seems to be "Why is the wrong value being returned for this argument?", but is actually something more along the lines of "How can I reorganize my code so that I can write a number of functions that accurately find an array element within an arbitrary schedule array"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it in a bit different way. May be helpful to you.

```js
let schedule = {
  "08:00 - 09:00": "Morning yoga",
  "09:00 - 10:00": "Breakfast",
  "10:00 - 13:00": "School Period",
  "13:00 - 14:00": "Basketball",
  "14:00 - 16:00": "Free Period",
  "16:00 - 17:00": "Evening Meal",
  "17:00 - 18:00": "Exercise Period",
  "18:00 - 19:00": "Shower Block",
  "19:00 - 22:00": "Evening Free Time",
  "22:00 - 23:00": "Evening Rollcall",
  "23:00 - 08:00": "Lights Out"
}
var getSchedule = function(time) {
let fullDaySchedule = {}
  Object.entries(schedule).forEach(([currentTime, work]) => {
    let startTime = +currentTime.split(" - ")[0].split(":")[0],
      endTime = +currentTime.split(" - ")[1].split(":")[0];

    (startTime > endTime) && (endTime = (23 - startTime) + (23 + endTime))

    for (let index = startTime; index <= endTime; index++) {
      fullDaySchedule[(index % 24)] = work;
    }
  })

  console.log(fullDaySchedule[+time.split(":")[0]])
}

// You can test this
getSchedule("02:00")
```

Comment: I see you suggested adding "let schedule" at the top. That's fine. You can now test this and let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hey Nitish Narang, @Tibrogargan is right. Using `let schedule = {
  "08:00 - 09:00": "Morning yoga",
  "09:00 - 10:00": "Breakfast",
  "10:00 - 13:00": "School Period",
  "13:00 - 14:00": "Basketball",
  "16:00 - 17:00": "Evening Meal",
  "17:00 - 18:00": "Exercise Period",
  "18:00 - 19:00": "Shower Block",
  "19:00 - 22:00": "Evening Free Time",
  "22:00 - 23:00": "Evening Rollcall",
  "23:00 - 08:00": "Lights Out"
};` combined with `getSchedule("15:00")` is not working.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you. With schedule object you are referring there is no data for time - "15:00", but it is there in your posted question.

Comment: I believe it's missing - "14:00 - 16:00": "Free Period" in schedule object.

Comment: "The solution you accepted does not solve the problem of a sparse schedule. Remove the "14:00 - 16:00": "Free Period" interval and try getSchedule("15:00")".

Comment: May I know what's the expected output for getSchedule("15:00") ?

Answer (score 1):

If you change the data structure it becomes much simpler.

```js
const schedule = {
  "Morning yoga": [800, 900],
  "Breakfast": [900, 1000]
};

const getSchedule = timeString => {
  const time = +timeString.replace(":", "");
  const result = [];
  for (const key in schedule) {
    if (time >= schedule[key][0] && time <= schedule[key][1]) {
      result.push(key);
    }
  }
  return result;
};

const result = getSchedule("09:22");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: While helpful, this does not actually answer the question.

Comment: The problem as I see it is that the code is overly complex. Debugging the OP code will not solve that.

Answer (score 0):

The script initially sets `scheduleIndex` to `0` (the default value) and never checks if a matching interval is found

Your logic will never match the "Lights Out" interval because the end value is less than the beginning value and your logic does not allow for this.

`getSchedule` therefore returns the "default" element from `schedule`, "Morning Yoga" instead of "Lights Out".

**Possible Solution(s):**

1. Change your logic to correctly match the "Lights Out" interval.
2. Split your "Lights Out" interval into two, "00:00 - 08:00" and "23:00 - 23:59" and keep the current logic
3. Keep your logic and add error checking (set `scheduleIndex` to an invalid value and test for that before you return a result) and remove the "Lights Out" interval from schedule and assume that anything not matched is this default interval.  (Shown below)

```js
let getSchedule = function(time) {
  let scheduleIndex = -1;
  let current = getMinute(time);
  let intervalArray = []

  for (let key in schedule)
    intervalArray.push([getMinute(key.split(" - ")[0]),
      getMinute(key.split(" - ")[1])
    ]);

  for (let index = 0; index < intervalArray.length; index++) {
    let interval = intervalArray[index]
    if (current >= interval[0] && current < interval[1]) {
      scheduleIndex = index;
      break;
    }
  };
  return -1 == scheduleIndex? "Lights Out" : schedule[Object.keys(schedule)[scheduleIndex]];
}

let getMinute = function(time) {
  let hour = parseInt(time.split(":")[0]),
    minute = parseInt(time.split(":")[1]);
  return minute + hour * 60;
}

let result = getSchedule("16:22")
console.log(result)

result = getSchedule("02:00")
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script>
  let schedule = {
    "08:00 - 09:00": "Morning yoga",
    "09:00 - 10:00": "Breakfast",
    "10:00 - 13:00": "School Period",
    "13:00 - 14:00": "Basketball",
    "14:00 - 16:00": "Free Period",
    "16:00 - 17:00": "Evening Meal",
    "17:00 - 18:00": "Exercise Period",
    "18:00 - 19:00": "Shower Block",
    "19:00 - 22:00": "Evening Free Time",
    "22:00 - 23:00": "Evening Rollcall",
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't want to deny that your answer is correct. I don't even think it's so bad. Unfortunately, for example, I am with this line `return -1 == scheduleIndex? ...` not as variable as before. I want to find a method where I can execute different `schedule` methods. Your method is rather inconvenient for me. And since I would like to leave my variable structure that way, your answer is more of a workaround. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your comment, sorry.  Do you mean to say you're confused by that line?  What exactly do you mean by "different `schedule` methods?  Either way, if you wanted anything more than just having your immediate problem fixed you should have put that in the question

Comment: No I'm absolutely not confused. The problem is that adding `"Lights Out"` as state inside the getSchedule-call is kind of a workaround. Because that makes the method not useable for different shedules where the "lights out" state could have a different name / position.

Comment: Right, but there is no mention of that requirement in the question.  You're moving the goal posts.  That being said, the general technique is applicable.  "If you don't find a match, return the default value".  Usually in this sort of situation, the default is passed into the function.  The part you should be using is "testing to see if a match was found", which is the root cause of your issue

Comment: The solution you accepted does not solve the problem of a sparse schedule.  Remove the "free time" interval and try `getSchedule("15:00")`

Comment: Ok. Yeah I see, you're right - I'll try to fix this. Thanks `:)`

Comment: Another way to view your problem is to write `getSchedule` as if it was intended to return the index of a schedule, or some default value if no match is found (like `Array.indexOf` returns -1), that would generalize the method so that the calling function could decide what to do instead of that logic being in `getSchedule`

Comment: If we don't tell schedule object for time "14:00 - 16:00", then what's the expected output for getSchedule("15:00") ? @ Tibrogargan

Comment: @NitishNarang No idea, the OP doesn't actually ask for code to handle that in the question - all he's asking for is to be able to get an array element that matches an input value but isn't happy with any of the answers (that pretty much all answer the question).  The actual problem is that his code does not handle error conditions (as well as being overly complicated with poor data structures).

Comment: Exactly!! OP never asked for it and whatevever question asked for my answer provided that and thats the reason jonas accepted my answer, which he later removed quoting your comment that it doesnt handle “15:00”. So thought to ask what is expected output. Anyways Thanks.

Comment: @NitishNarang He seems to want some method that he can apply to an arbitrary schedule object, without actually describing what that is.

Answer (score 0):

I've refacored your code `a bit`. It's done in more functional and I believe readable way. Also I took into account some edge cases (not all of the of course because it's not the case I believe). Take a look at this bad boy:

```
// Keep in mind that for e.g. `14:00` you have two parameters that fullfil the requirement: 
// `Basketball` and `Free Period`. 
// This constrain should be specified in the code somewhere.
// Otherwise the first value will be taken.
let schedule = {
    "08:00 - 09:00" : "Morning yoga",
    "09:00 - 10:00" : "Breakfast",
    "10:00 - 13:00" : "School Period",
    "13:00 - 14:00" : "Basketball",
    "14:00 - 16:00" : "Free Period",
    "16:00 - 17:00" : "Evening Meal",
    "17:00 - 18:00" : "Exercise Period",
    "18:00 - 19:00" : "Shower Block",
    "19:00 - 22:00" : "Evening Free Time",
    "22:00 - 23:00" : "Evening Rollcall",
    "23:00 - 08:00" : "Lights Out"
  }


let newSchedule = Object
  .entries(schedule)
  .reduce((acc, entry) => {
    const newInterval = {
      from: Number(entry[0].slice(0,5).replace(':','')),
      to: Number(entry[0].slice(-5).replace(':','')),
      value: entry[1],
    };
    return [...acc, newInterval];
  }, [])
  .reduce((acc, { from, to, value}) => {
    // this step is only needed when you can't set ranges in `schedule` object manually
    let intervals = [{ from, to, value }];
    if(from > to) {
      intervals = [
        { 
          from, 
          to: 2400,
          value,
        },
        { 
          from: 0, 
          to,
          value,
        },
      ];
    }
    return [...acc, ...intervals];
  }, []);

const getSchedule = (time) => {
  const timeAsNumber = Number(time.replace(':', ''));
  return newSchedule.find(interval => {
    return timeAsNumber >= interval.from && timeAsNumber <= interval.to;
  }).value
}

console.log(getSchedule('02:00'))
console.log(getSchedule('18:00'))
```

I encourage you to refactor it further e.g. into more functional approach, more performant, Or just cleaner.